# SQL group by between

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL code

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM crate_log 
GROUP BY user_id, last_crate - first_crate 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

What i want to do is getting all results from "last_crate - first_crate" 5 up and 5 down and count them.

Like:

```
last_crate - first_crate BETWEEN last_crate - first_crate - 5 
                             AND last_crate - first_crate + 5
```

I tried a few things but don't know how to do it.

btw.

```
last_crate - first_crate
```

Is just the difference that i need

Hope you understand me..

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: I use MySQL, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT user_id, last_crate - first_crate, COUNT(*) 
FROM crate_log 
GROUP BY user_id, last_crate - first_crate 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND ABS(last_crate - first_crate)<=5
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Press the `Enter` key once more after _about_ to re-format :)

Comment: Thank you, but im getting an error. "Unknown column 'last_crate' in 'having clause'"

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this comment before. My mistake, the abs(...)<=5 should be in the where clause not in the having clause.